# How to find the graphic primitive that is clicked in a group

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have a Group that has many different graphic primitives in it. If I click on the group I can get a reference to it in MouseEvent(event).currentTarget. But how do I know if I have clicked on a graphic primitive?

Example Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function group1_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                trace("event target="+ event.target);
                // traces the group
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Group width="500" height="500" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
             mouseDown="group1_mouseDownHandler(event)"
             mouseEnabledWhereTransparent="true">


        <s:Rect x="10" width="100" height="100" radiusX="10" radiusY="10">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#ff0000"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <s:Ellipse x="150" width="100" height="100">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#ff0000"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>

    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The classes in package spark.primitives are not inherited from InteractiveObject, they won't dispatch  mouse event.
Add them to different groups, one to one. And add listeners to the groups.

Comment: This was my first thought too.  Although, it may lead to excess number of groups / components which could hurt app efficiency.  It may be possible to do some calculations based on the mouse click x and y events and the locations of the shapes.

Comment: That's one possibility but like Reboog said, it could hurt app efficiency. I was looking for an example that used a hit test or looped through the graphic elements and checked the x and y positions. I haven't done either which is why I posted the question. :)

Comment: If you add all in one group, hit test has no use. Checking x & y can do it, but you'll need lots of calculations.